# Dataframe to nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 3 columns "ID" , "Date" , "House_Price_Index" and I want to convert this into a dictionary looking like:

```
{ID:{"Date":"Value" , "House_Price_Index":"Value"}}
```

Here's a sample of the dataframe:

```
ID      Date  House_Price_Index
0      1/1/1975            61.0900
1      1/1/1976            65.5250
2      1/1/1977            73.4350
3      1/1/1978            83.7450
4      1/1/1979            95.1325
5      1/1/1980           102.6675
```

So the output should be:

```
{0:{"Date":"1/1/1975","House_Price_Index":"61.0900"}}
```

... so on and so forth

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried pandas `Dataframe.to_dict` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with convert `ID` to index (because column):

```
d = df.set_index('ID').to_dict('index')
print (d)
{0: {'Date': '1/1/1975', 'House_Price_Index': 61.09}, 
 1: {'Date': '1/1/1976', 'House_Price_Index': 65.525},
 2: {'Date': '1/1/1977', 'House_Price_Index': 73.435},
 3: {'Date': '1/1/1978', 'House_Price_Index': 83.745},
 4: {'Date': '1/1/1979', 'House_Price_Index': 95.1325},
 5: {'Date': '1/1/1980', 'House_Price_Index': 102.6675}}
```